# UITableViewCell Accessory Repeating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, I have a detailed view where the user can edit attributes of for example a person, their name, address etc.

In two cells, rather than being able to select them to edit their contents, they have a right accessory, a UISwitch, however sometimes, its inconsistent, but they replicate onto other cells in my last section.

I have been scanning my code dozens of times over with a fine comb and can't find the damn cause. What might cause this? Here is the code that I use to create the UISwitch on just a single cell:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Confirmed";

    //Make the cell unselectable
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    //Create and add uiswitch
    confirmedSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [confirmedSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchConfirmedStatus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [confirmedSwitch setOn:[venue.isConfirmed boolValue]];
    cell.accessoryView = confirmedSwitch;
}
```

So you expect it to only show up on that cell, see anything odd with that code? I have checked my if statements and all my brackets indexPath checks are correct.

Anyone see this before or have any clues?

Comment: Sounds like a cell reuse issue. When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` you get a recycled cell - (you may have added the switch to this cell). What you'll need to do remove the view you add when you recycle the cell

Comment: Is this code inside cellForRowAtIndexPath?  Are you using a single reusable cell identifier?  If so, what do you do if you get a cached cell back and it *doesn't* match your section/row test?

Comment: Ahh, I guess the clue is in the name 'Reuse'! I am using this, so simply turning the accessory view for ALL my other cells to nil fixed this! Guess I was thinking too much, thought there might be a larger problem behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because of `reusability` issues in the `UITableView`. You probably use the same `identifier` for all cells and this causes the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be implemented in other rows (when you scroll up and down).

This is a common problem when you are developing applications with `tableView` and there are plenty of questions like this on StackOverflow.

As a general solution, you will need to do either of these.

1. Use different identifiers when you assign `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for each cell. This is fairly simple, and you just need to assign different identifiers for them.
2. Subclass you `UITableViewController`, and create your own `CustomTableViewController` which will implement the necessary components in the `cell`. I believe you will need to override the `set Layout Subviews` method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a array in view will appear and add object 0 for this row and 1 for all other rows and then in  cellForRowAtIndexPath check if array has 0 at that index if it has then put switch otherwise nill..

```
for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        [arrayForSwitch addObject:@"0"];
    }
    else
    {
        [arrayForSwitch addObject:@"1"];
    }
}
```

then in cellForRowAtIndexPath write condition

```
if([arrayForSwitch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
    cell.accessoryView = confirmedSwitch;
}
else
{

    cell.accessoryView =UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

it will now remain same